# How to test useFocusEffect with react-native-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, react-native-testing-library

I use useFocusEffect from @react-navigation/native and I try to test the component.
I tried what @meshantz suggested on [react-navigation-hooks: How to test useFocusEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114670/react-navigation-hooks-how-to-test-usefocuseffect) but when I run the tests it says ***Cannot read property 'Provider' of undefined***.

Can you please explain what I am doing wrong? I'm new to testing in react-native and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your test file, but if you're getting that error then check you've imported `NavgationContext`:

```
import { NavigationContext } from '@react-navigation/native'
```

Also confirm that your file has a `tsx` extension and that you have `@react-navigation/native` in your `node_modules` folder and `package.json`.